# Yeoman is not installing/updating latest version of generator with github

Tags: jekyll, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am working on with generator-jekyllrb and it uses grunt. When i run grunt command in the terminal it gives those errors.

```
Gruntfile.js
  line 63  col 24  Strings must use singlequote.
  line 64  col 21  Strings must use singlequote.
  line 65  col 34  Strings must use singlequote.
  line 74  col 42  Strings must use singlequote.
  line 91  col 24  Strings must use singlequote.
  line 92  col 21  Strings must use singlequote.
  line 93  col 34  Strings must use singlequote.

✖ 7 problems
```

It gives error because of double quotes at these lines in my Gruntfile.js file.

```
...
options: {
          server: {
            baseDir: [
              ".jekyll",
              ".tmp",
              "<%= yeoman.app %>"
...
```

But when i check the [jekyllrb](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb/blob/master/app/templates/Gruntfile.js)'s github page, it can be seen that this problem is solved and Gruntfile.js is committed with lines with single quoted.

*Gruntfile.js   Replace double quotes with single quotes in Gruntfile.js    a year ago*

I tried to remove/reinstall and update jekyllrb,neither works. It still downloads jekylrrb with double quoted one.

Answer (score 0):

In `.jshintrc`, you can change

```
"quotmark": "single",
```

to

```
"quotmark": "double",
```

See jshint doc http://jshint.com/docs/options/

Comment: Works. Because i have double both single and double quotes in my gruntfile, i have changed it to true which documentation says --> **true** if you don't want to enforce one particular style. But i still don't get it why i can't install committed version of jekyllrb via terminal?

Comment: This really looks like a linter warning. Do you have a repository ?

Comment: no, i install it via npm `npm install -g generator-jekyllrb`

Comment: I repeat, in order to help you debug, do you have code available in a github repository ?

Comment: No i haven't. I solved the issue with your suggestion, only think i ask is why that command i gave previous comment isn't downloading updated version of generator-jekyllrb(in the github page) which hasn't this problem?

Comment: But why are you using generator-jekyllrb for a single site ? It's far better to learn things one a a time. Start with a regular Jekyll.